# Multiplying large matrices with dask

Tags: python, matrix, dask

I am working on a project which basically boils down to solving the matrix equation

```
A.dot(x) = d
```

where `A` is a matrix with dimensions roughly 10 000 000 by 2000 (I would like to increase this in both directions eventually).

`A` obviously does not fit in memory, so this has to be parallelized. I do that by solving `A.T.dot(A).dot(x) = A.T.dot(d)` instead. `A.T` will have dimensions 2000 by 2000. It can be calculated by dividing `A` and `d` into chunks `A_i` and `d_i`, along the rows, calculate `A_i.T.dot(A_i)` and `A_i.T.dot(d_i)`, and sum these. Perfect for parallellizing. I have been able to implement this with the multiprocessing module, but it is 1) hard to scale any further (increasing `A` in both dimensions), due to memory use, and 2) not pretty (and therefore not easy to maintain).

Dask seems to be a very promising library for solving both these problems, and I have made some attempts. My `A` matrix is complicated to calculate: It is based on approximately 15 different arrays (with size equal to the number of rows in `A`), and some are used in an iterative algorithm to evaluate associated Legendre function. When the chunks are small (10000 rows), it takes a very long time to build the task graph, and it takes a lot of memory (the memory increase coincides with the call to the iterative algorithm). When the chunks are larger (50000 rows), the memory consumption prior to calculations is a lot smaller, but it is rapidly depleted when calculating `A.T.dot(A)`. I have tried with `cache.Chest`, but it significantly slows down the calculations.

The task graph must be very large and complicated - calling `A._visualize()` crashes. With simpler `A` matrices, it works to do this directly (see response by @MRocklin). Is there a way for me to simplify it?

Any advice on how to get around this would be highly appreciated.

<strike>As a toy example, I tried</strike>

```
A = da.ones((2e3, 1e7), chunks = (2e3, 1e3)) 
(A.T.dot(A)).compute()
```

This also failed, using up all the memory with only one core being active. With `chunks = (2e3, 1e5)`, all cores start almost immediately, but `MemoryError` appears within 1 second (I have 15 GB on my current computer). `chunks = (2e3, 1e4)` was more promising, but it ended up consuming all memory as well.

Edit:
I struckthrough the toy example test, because the dimensions were wrong, and corrected the dimensions in the rest. As @MRocklin says, it does work with the right dimensions. I added a question which I now think is more relevant to my problem.

Edit2:
This is a much simplified example of what I was trying to do. The problem is, I believe, the recursions involved in defining the columns in `A`.

```
import dask.array as da

N = 1e6
M = 500

x = da.random.random((N, 1), chunks = 5*M)

# my actual 
A_dict = {0:x}
for i in range(1, M):
    A_dict[i] = 2*A_dict[i-1]
A = da.hstack(tuple(A_dict.values()))
A = A.rechunk((M*5, M))
ATA = A.T.dot(A)
```

This seems to lead to a very complicated task graph, which takes up a lot of memory before the calculations even start.

I have now solved this by placing the recursion in a function, with `numpy` arrays, and more or less do `A = x.map_blocks(...)`.

As a second note, once I have the `A` matrix task graph, calculating `A.T.dot(A)` directly does seem to give some memory issues (memory usage is not very stable). I therefore explicitly calculate it in chunks, and sum the results. Even with these workarounds, dask makes a big difference in speed and readability.

Comment: How are you chunking your array now?  `chunks=(10000, 2000)`?  Your idea of having a toy example is really helpful because it allows me to play with things locally.  Can you produce another toy example that is more representative of your problem?

Comment: Another toy example is added. I found a solution, with `map_blocks`, but there may be more elegant ways of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

Your output is very very large.

```
>>> A.T.dot(A).shape
(10000000, 10000000)
```

Perhaps you intended to compute this with the transposes in the other direction?

```
>>> A.dot(A.T).shape
(2000, 2000)
```

This still takes a while (it's a large computation) but it does complete.

Comment: Thanks for answering! You are absolutely right. I messed up the dimensions in my questions, and also when I tried my toy example. I will edit the question.